# Console Application accepting '/' into password even though it shouldn't

Tags: c#

I have created a `Console` application in `C#`. I do not want my application to accept `'/'`, however it continues to accept it as a character. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Student_Enrollment_System
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome To the Student Enrollment System Please Choose One Of The Below Opions");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("(1) Sign Up");
            Console.WriteLine("(2) Sign In");
            Console.WriteLine("(3) Update password");
            Console.WriteLine("(4) Recover password");
            Console.WriteLine("(5) Exit");

            int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (number)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("type Student First Name");
                {
                    string filepath = "C:\\SES\\User.txt";
                    //StreamWriter filewr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\G510\Documents\Student Enrollment System\User.txt", true);

                    string studentname = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Type in Student ID");
                    string student_id = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.WriteLine("Type in Student PassWord");
                    string student_password = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("data has been added to the same file name");

                        StreamWriter filewr = new StreamWriter(filepath, true);

                        filewr.WriteLine(studentname);
                        filewr.WriteLine(student_id);

                        do
                        {
                        } while (student_password.Contains('/') == true);

                        MessageBox.Show("forward slash is not allowed ");

                        filewr.WriteLine(student_password);
                        filewr.Flush();
                        filewr.Close();
                    }

                    else if (!File.Exists(filepath))
                    {
                        StreamWriter filewr = new StreamWriter(filepath);

                        filewr.WriteLine(studentname);
                        filewr.WriteLine(student_id);

                        do
                        {
                        } while (student_password.Contains('/') == true);

                        MessageBox.Show("forward slash is not allowed ");

                        filewr.WriteLine(student_password);
                        filewr.Flush();
                        filewr.Close();
                    }
                    return;

                    Console.WriteLine("Thanks For Signing Up Press Any Key To Exit");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("(2) Sign In");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("(3) Update password");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("(4) Recover password");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("(5) Exit");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: you need to format your code correctly so its more readable

Comment: Format your question properly or soon ti will be closed

Comment: I've tidied your question for you - but you really need to put some more effort in in the future. That was a right mess, and you can't be expecting the community to help you out posting such poor quality.

Comment: sorry guy am new here.
somebody told me this,  use do- while instead of if here? This "if " will not stop program go to further even if password contains /
i tried this 
  do {
            //am i messing something here
        } while (student_password.Contains('/') == true);
          MessageBox.Show("forward slash is not allowed ");
but nothing happens console still runs does nothing am messing  something in the do block

Comment: Click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19321411) below your question and put your code there. Do not put code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
string student_password = Console.ReadLine();
if (student_password.Contains('/') == true)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("/ is not allowed"); 
}
```

to

```
string student_password = Console.ReadLine();
while (student_password.Contains('/') == true)
{
    MessageBox.Show("/ is not allowed");
    student_password = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now as long as `student_password` contains a slash, you will be asked to enter a new password.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few problems in your code:

Firstly you shouldn't be using `MessageBox.Show` within a console application, they're designed for WinForm applications. It won't be guaranteed to work in all environments.

Secondly, if you spot a bad character you don't do anything, try something like:

```
  if(student_password.Contains('/') == true) 
  { 
      Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but passwords can't contain '/'". Please try again");
      Console.Write("Password: ");
      student_password = Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

You can then try again, although you'd need to move your password bit into a new function. Alternatively just abort:

```
  if(student_password.Contains('/') == true) 
  { 
      Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but passwords can't contain '/'". Aborting");
      return;
  }
```

Finally I'd seriously consider why can't the user have a `/` in their password. It's a special character, it's going to help with security. Don't make passwords restrictions weaker in general just for your benefit.

Answer (score -1):

You do not react to "/" char.

Try something like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(" / is not allowed. Aborting ");
return;
```

or

```
student_password.Replace('/', '')
```

Comment: You should never do the latter. The user has type a password, and you've just swapped our 1 character. How do they know that? Their passwords will never match when typing them in.